# Not Able to access user privileges for root in mysql

Tags: mysql, permissions

I accidentally deleted all privileges for root and users. I would like to know how to restore them. I don't have access to USER privileges for any other user.

Answer (score 0):

Restart mysqld_safe with this option added --skip-grant-tables

That will work only from localhost, and gives you a clean slate for creating a new root password.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the mysqld service

```
service mysqld stop
```

Launch with skip grant option

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &> /dev/null &
```

Login

```
mysql -u root
```

Recreate the user

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepasswordorsomething';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Flush the privileges

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Kill mysqld

```
kill $( ps aux | grep mysqld_safe | awk '{print $2}' )
```

Restart the service, reenabling the grant table.

```
service mysqld start
```

This should have recreated the `root` user that you had previously.